# Laravel email template styling

Tags: php, laravel

Css is not working in email templates so any Emails for my clients look ugly, After a lot of googling I have seen solutions on Laravel css inline but I don't know how to use them,

Any solutions so as to help my css load

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title')
    XXXX | WELCOME
@endsection``
@section('body')
<div class="page text-center">

  <!-- Page Head-->
        <!-- Page Contents-->
  <main class="page-content">
    <!-- Search Engine-->
    <section class="section-98 section-sm-110">
      <div class="shell">
        <div class="offset-sm-top-66">
           <center>
            <img class='img-responsive' style='margin-top: -20px;margin-left: -5px;' width='329' height='67' src="{{URL::to('/images/icon1.png')}}" alt=''/>
          </center>
          <!-- Responsive-tabs-->
          <div data-type="horizontal" class="responsive-tabs responsive-tabs-classic">
            <p class="text-center alert alert-info">Welcome to XXXX <br> please verify your account by entering digits sent via sms.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
@endsection
```

Above is the sample template

Thank you.

Comment: external CSS, is problematic, that leaves `<style>` tags on the page and inline `style=""` attributes.  Emails can be real finicky, it's best to keep the design as simple as possible, with as few images as you can get away with.

Comment: In general, when you're designing HTML emails, pretend that it's 1999 and don't use any fancy HTML and CSS. If you want it to work in most clients, use tables and inline styling.

Comment: Is there any library or any other pre-compile solution?

Answer (score 11):

Laravel will automatically move the style from your theme's CSS file and put it inline. See **Customizing The CSS** in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail).

1. Publish the default theme's layout and css: `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`.
2. This will give you a `default.css` file in `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes`. The "default" in `default.css` is your theme name.
3. (Optional) Copy the `resources/views/vendor/mail` directory to wherever it makes the most sense for your app. e.g. `resources/views/mail`
4. (Optional) Customize the HTML in `mail/layout.blade.php` or the CSS in `mail/themes/default.css`.
5. Set up your config. Edit `/config/mail.php` and give the path to your mail layouts and your theme name:

```php
    // in config/mail.php

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Send Emails Using Markdown
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',            # The name of your theme (default.css)
        'paths' => [                     # The path to your /html and /text dirs
            resource_path('views/emails/layouts')
        ]
    ],
```

5. (Optional) If you want to create multiple "themes", copy and rename the stylesheet - e.g. `mytheme1.css`. Then you use the name of the CSS file as a property on your Mailable using that theme.

```php
   // in e.g. app/Mail/MyMailable.php

    /**
     * The name of the theme that should be used when formatting the message.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $theme = "mytheme1.css";
```

The CSS from your theme file will "automatically be in-lined within the HTML representations of your Markdown mail messages."

Answer (score 2):

It's correct to use inline css for email.

if we take this line of code:

```
<img class='img-responsive' style='margin-top: -20px;margin-left: -5px;' width='329' height='67' src="{{URL::to('/images/icon1.png')}}" alt=''/>
```

the inline css start at the style tag. At this moment the class tag does nothing. To fix that you kan put a `<style></style>` in the header of the email. So you get somthing like this:

`<head><style>.img-responsive {margin-top: -20px; margin-left: -5px; width=329px; height=67px}</style></head>`

now you can use the img-responsive class in your code.

Do know that if you are using bootstrap css that you need to put that in your style code to.

Answer (score 0):

Use markdown templates
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#markdown-mailables

Create a view:

```
php artisan make:mail MailableClass --markdown=markdown_view
```

Use markdown( ) method to specify your view:

```
#/app/Mail/MailableClass.php
    public function build() {
        return $this->from(…)
                    ->markdown('view_name');
    }
```

Also you can change the default theme by:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

Your default styles will be located in /resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes/default.css

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I did:

1. create some directory to hold your source files for the templates, css and other things related (perhaps images). I've put it under resources/src/emails/ with a structure like this:

`/ - holds package.json and gulp files.
/assets/stylesheets - put your (s)css files here
/assets/templates - just put your template files here`

2. install the gems 'premailer' and 'nokogiri' (preferably use a Gemfile) (You will need Ruby for this)
3. You will need the following packages installed with npm:

   - gulp
   - gulp-premailer
   - gulp-html-entities
   - and for my specific case, we also use gulp-sass and coffee-script.
4. Run gulp and build your templates with the following gulp file (gulpfile.coffee, as this is coffee-script)

   ```
   gulp = require('gulp')
   premailer = require('gulp-premailer')
   sass = require('gulp-sass')
   entities = require('gulp-html-entities')

   build = 'build/'
   templates_dest = './../../views/emails/'
   images_dest = '../../../public/img/emails/'

   gulp.task 'css', ->
       gulp.src 'assets/stylesheets/mail.scss'
           .pipe sass().on('error', sass.logError)
           .pipe gulp.dest build + 'css'

   gulp.task 'templates', ->
       gulp.src 'assets/templates/*.php'
       .pipe premailer()
           .on 'error', (err) ->
               console.log err
       .pipe entities('decode')
       .pipe gulp.dest templates_dest

   gulp.task 'images', ->
       gulp.src 'assets/images/**/*'
       .pipe gulp.dest images_dest

   gulp.task 'watch', ->
       gulp.watch "assets/templates/*.php", ['templates']
       gulp.watch "assets/images/**/*", ['images']
       gulp.watch ["assets/stylesheets/*", "assets/stylesheets/**/*"], ['css', 'templates']

   gulp.task 'default', ['css', 'templates', 'images']
   gulp.task 'build', ['css', 'templates', 'images']
   gulp.task 'watch', ['css', 'templates', 'images', 'watch']
   ```

You will have to tweak this a bit to suit your own needs. I've only got 1 scss file for instance at the moment. We also move images used to a specific folder under public/, etc.

The biggest problem I ran into is that the premailer gem replaces characters with it's html entity. This offcourse is a problem because in our blade templates we use '{' and '}' as well as '>' (when using something like $model->name)
That's solved now with the use of the html-entities lib, to decode that back. This solution seems to work for me. But just keep in mind, you might very well run into problems.